# geting previous purshase Non Consumable not work in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I have application in m console account and i create non consumable product for purshase.

I use the the original docs for my code (https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase)

**Note**: I'm useng this app for android.

And this is my code :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase_android/billing_client_wrappers.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase_android/in_app_purchase_android.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase_storekit/in_app_purchase_storekit.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase_storekit/store_kit_wrappers.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(_MyApp());
}

const String _kUpgradeId = 'remove_ads';
const List<String> _kProductIds = <String>[
  _kUpgradeId,
];

class _MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<_MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<_MyApp> {
  final InAppPurchase _inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;
  late StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>> _subscription;
  List<String> _notFoundIds = <String>[];
  List<ProductDetails> _products = <ProductDetails>[];
  List<PurchaseDetails> _purchases = <PurchaseDetails>[];
  bool _isAvailable = false;
  bool _purchasePending = false;
  bool _loading = true;
  String? _queryProductError;

  @override
  void initState() {
    final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated =
        _inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;
    _subscription =
        purchaseUpdated.listen((List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
      _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
    }, onDone: () {
      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (Object error) {
      // handle error here.
    });
    initStoreInfo();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> initStoreInfo() async {
    final bool isAvailable = await _inAppPurchase.isAvailable();
    if (!isAvailable) {
      setState(() {
        _isAvailable = isAvailable;
        _products = <ProductDetails>[];
        _purchases = <PurchaseDetails>[];
        _notFoundIds = <String>[];
        _purchasePending = false;
        _loading = false;
      });
      return;
    }

    final ProductDetailsResponse productDetailResponse =
        await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(_kProductIds.toSet());
    if (productDetailResponse.error != null) {
      setState(() {
        _queryProductError = productDetailResponse.error!.message;
        _isAvailable = isAvailable;
        _products = productDetailResponse.productDetails;
        _purchases = <PurchaseDetails>[];
        _notFoundIds = productDetailResponse.notFoundIDs;
        _purchasePending = false;
        _loading = false;
      });
      return;
    }

    if (productDetailResponse.productDetails.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _queryProductError = null;
        _isAvailable = isAvailable;
        _products = productDetailResponse.productDetails;
        _purchases = <PurchaseDetails>[];
        _notFoundIds = productDetailResponse.notFoundIDs;
        _purchasePending = false;
        _loading = false;
      });
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      _isAvailable = isAvailable;
      _products = productDetailResponse.productDetails;
      _notFoundIds = productDetailResponse.notFoundIDs;
      _purchasePending = false;
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      final InAppPurchaseStoreKitPlatformAddition iosPlatformAddition =
          _inAppPurchase
              .getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseStoreKitPlatformAddition>();
      iosPlatformAddition.setDelegate(null);
    }
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> stack = <Widget>[];
    if (_queryProductError == null) {
      stack.add(
        ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildConnectionCheckTile(),
            _buildProductList(),
            _buildRestoreButton(),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      stack.add(Center(
        child: Text(_queryProductError!),
      ));
    }
    if (_purchasePending) {
      stack.add(
        Stack(
          children: const <Widget>[
            Opacity(
              opacity: 0.3,
              child: ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('IAP Example'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: stack,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Card _buildConnectionCheckTile() {
    if (_loading) {
      return const Card(child: ListTile(title: Text('Trying to connect...')));
    }
    final Widget storeHeader = ListTile(
      leading: Icon(_isAvailable ? Icons.check : Icons.block,
          color: _isAvailable ? Colors.green : ThemeData.light().errorColor),
      title:
          Text('The store is ${_isAvailable ? 'available' : 'unavailable'}.'),
    );
    final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[storeHeader];

    if (!_isAvailable) {
      children.addAll(<Widget>[
        const Divider(),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Not connected',
              style: TextStyle(color: ThemeData.light().errorColor)),
          subtitle: const Text(
              'Unable to connect to the payments processor. Has this app been configured correctly? See the example README for instructions.'),
        ),
      ]);
    }
    return Card(child: Column(children: children));
  }

  Card _buildProductList() {
    if (_loading) {
      return const Card(
          child: ListTile(
              leading: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              title: Text('Fetching products...')));
    }
    if (!_isAvailable) {
      return const Card();
    }
    const ListTile productHeader = ListTile(title: Text('Products for Sale'));
    final List<ListTile> productList = <ListTile>[];
    if (_notFoundIds.isNotEmpty) {
      productList.add(ListTile(
          title: Text('[${_notFoundIds.join(", ")}] not found',
              style: TextStyle(color: ThemeData.light().errorColor)),
          subtitle: const Text(
              'This app needs special configuration to run. Please see example/README.md for instructions.')));
    }

    final Map<String, PurchaseDetails> purchases =
        Map<String, PurchaseDetails>.fromEntries(
            _purchases.map((PurchaseDetails purchase) {
      if (purchase.pendingCompletePurchase) {
        _inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchase);
      }
      return MapEntry<String, PurchaseDetails>(purchase.productID, purchase);
    }));
    productList.addAll(_products.map(
      (ProductDetails productDetails) {
        final PurchaseDetails? previousPurchase = purchases[productDetails.id];
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(
            productDetails.title,
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            productDetails.description,
          ),
          trailing: previousPurchase != null
              ? IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => confirmPriceChange(context),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.upgrade))
              : TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green[800],
                    primary: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    late PurchaseParam purchaseParam;

                    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                      final GooglePlayPurchaseDetails? oldSubscription =
                          _getOldSubscription(productDetails, purchases);

                      purchaseParam = GooglePlayPurchaseParam(
                          productDetails: productDetails,
                          changeSubscriptionParam: (oldSubscription != null)
                              ? ChangeSubscriptionParam(
                                  oldPurchaseDetails: oldSubscription,
                                  prorationMode:
                                      ProrationMode.immediateWithTimeProration,
                                )
                              : null);
                    } else {
                      purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(
                        productDetails: productDetails,
                      );
                    }

                    _inAppPurchase.buyNonConsumable(
                        purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
                  },
                  child: Text(productDetails.price),
                ),
        );
      },
    ));

    return Card(
        child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[productHeader, const Divider()] + productList));
  }

  Widget _buildRestoreButton() {
    if (_loading) {
      return Container();
    }

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              primary: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () => _inAppPurchase.restorePurchases(),
            child: const Text('Restore purchases'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void showPendingUI() {
    setState(() {
      _purchasePending = true;
    });
  }

  Future<void> deliverProduct(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
    setState(() {
      _purchases.add(purchaseDetails);
      _purchasePending = false;
    });
  }

  void handleError(IAPError error) {
    setState(() {
      _purchasePending = false;
    });
  }

  Future<bool> _verifyPurchase(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) {
    return Future<bool>.value(true);
  }

  void _handleInvalidPurchase(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) {}

  Future<void> _listenToPurchaseUpdated(
      List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
    for (final PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
        showPendingUI();
      } else {
        if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
          handleError(purchaseDetails.error!);
        } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased ||
            purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
          final bool valid = await _verifyPurchase(purchaseDetails);
          if (valid) {
            deliverProduct(purchaseDetails);
          } else {
            _handleInvalidPurchase(purchaseDetails);
            return;
          }
        }
        if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
          await _inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> confirmPriceChange(BuildContext context) async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition androidAddition =
          _inAppPurchase
              .getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>();
      final BillingResultWrapper priceChangeConfirmationResult =
          await androidAddition.launchPriceChangeConfirmationFlow(
        sku: 'purchaseId',
      );
      if (priceChangeConfirmationResult.responseCode == BillingResponse.ok) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Price change accepted'),
        ));
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(
            priceChangeConfirmationResult.debugMessage ??
                'Price change failed with code ${priceChangeConfirmationResult.responseCode}',
          ),
        ));
      }
    }
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      final InAppPurchaseStoreKitPlatformAddition iapStoreKitPlatformAddition =
          _inAppPurchase
              .getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseStoreKitPlatformAddition>();
      await iapStoreKitPlatformAddition.showPriceConsentIfNeeded();
    }
  }

  GooglePlayPurchaseDetails? _getOldSubscription(
      ProductDetails productDetails, Map<String, PurchaseDetails> purchases) {
    GooglePlayPurchaseDetails? oldSubscription;

    return oldSubscription;
  }
}
```

I can purshase prodct with this code but the problem is ***i can't get the previous purshases***.

In anyone can help me with this, please.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `_inAppPurchase.restorePurchases()` its listened in the same stream thats mentioned below

```
final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated =
        _inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;
    _subscription =
purchaseUpdated.listen((List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
      _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
    }, onDone: () {
      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (Object error) {
      // handle error here.
    });
```

Comment: i already used this part of code and still not work! can you tell me why?

Comment: Do you have any past non consumable product purchase?

Comment: yes i do, i'm using test email, if i try to purshase againe it show me are allready prshase, but it didn't fill in purshase variable.

Comment: Yeah non consumable can be purchased only once

Comment: so what can we do for solve it?
it's beter if you can provide me correct code